# c# a nice notice box

Tags: c#, messagebox, notice

Is there any code for a nice notice box (Even a dll would be fine)
Like the one kaspersky antivirus shows? Because in my script I use a lot of
message box and the end-user start to complain that they need to click okay every time.

Comment: WPF or WinForms? Please add tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this [exemple](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx) on CodeProject.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a custom control, which inherits from the message box and then you design it as per your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not an actual answer to your question, but if you users complain about the number of message boxes they need to "click away" (like you mention yourself), are you perhaps using them too much or for the wrong reasons?

Perhaps other ways of showing messages are more approriate in some cases, like a status bar, a dialog with a message log, or different way of structuring dialogs/workflows in your application?

Comment: It need to be seen by the user cause something it's important some time not(it comes from the same function so you can't sort them) so I guess that a notice box would be best fit.